# Format a Numeric Value in Gridview Without Boundfield

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is used as a datasource in my Gridview. Some columns are numeric and I want them to be formatted in Money format with decimal and commas.

I was able to achieve that before by using a dataformatstring attribute in the boundfield like this example

```
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Non VAT" DataField="nonvat" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}" />
```

however,  in my case, there is no Boundfield available because I have made a logic that boundfield is not required.

Are there other means to do it, aside from formatting it right away in the SQL?

Comment: What are you using now instead of BoundField to display your data? TemplateField? Something else? Anyway, post the way you use it now

Comment: autogeneratecolumn is set to true. So the stored procedure as the data source is actually making the data display in the gridview of course hard coded in ASP.net.

Comment: When boundfield is used, autogeneratecolumns is set to false.

Comment: Well, if you generate your columns you do not control output in any way, so you cannot format individual columns. Your options are to go back to using bound fields, or preprocess your data source before you feed it to gridview.

Comment: so there ano means? how about doing it on rowdatabound event?

Comment: Oh, well, you could use row data bound event, sure. Although I would consider anything except Bound/Template fields for this use case to be a hack. Different levels of dirtiness, but still a hack. The fields mechanism is there to allow customization of grid view column appearance, why would anyone want to work it around to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `RowDataBound`, presuming `nonvat` is a decimal and it's first column:

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
         decimal nonvat = (decimal)row["nonvat"];
         e.Row.Cells[0].Text = nonvat.ToString("#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work, the fact that OP deliberately uses autogenerated columns suggests that the number of columns is dynamic. Then OP may have no way of knowing which column index goes to which column.

Comment: what if the column name is a not a static one? what can I put in the "nonvat" part?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer: you can always use the `int`-indexer: `decimal nonvat = (decimal)row[0];`

Comment: @Andrei: if OP does know nothing about his data there is no logic that could solve this problem. So either he has to know the index or the column name, the type is also relevant because you cannot format any type as a number.

Comment: @Andrei yes you are correct. so maybe I will now resort to my last option, which is format it in SQL .